# How can I acccess firestore data from a python script run locally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database and I want to be able to upload data to it using a local script:

```
#!/bin/env python3
from google.cloud import firestore # google-cloud-firestore==2.1.1
client = firestore.Client()
test = client.collection("test")
doc = next(test.stream())
```

This throws `google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions.`

I am logged in via both the `gcloud` and `firebase` commands, and my firestore rules are open:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
```

I am the Owner of the GCP project, and client.project is the right project.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a service account works, but you need a special firebase one rather than a GCP one.

`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/${projectId}/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk`

Service accounts created in GCP do not work, even if they have admin permissions.

Also, the firebase_admin sdk seems to allow more configuration as to the credential than google.cloud.firestore.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate(f"/home/user/Downloads/{projectId}-firebase-adminsdk-{random...}.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
# or set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the account path

db = firestore.client()

test = db.collection("test")

doc = next(test.stream())
```